# How can I use Web Api Service with OdataController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am calling a service with this url: http://localhost:7951/odata/Student
but I got error

> 404 not found

Where am I doing wrong?

My DbContext class is as below:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{ 
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=FrameworkConnStr")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentAddress> StudentAddresses { get; set; }
}

[Table("M_DEMIR.STUDENT")]
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentAddress = new HashSet<StudentAddress>();
    }

    [Column("ID"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("NAME", TypeName = "varchar2"), MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("SURNAME", TypeName = "varchar2"), MaxLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentAddress> StudentAddress { get; set; }
}

[Table("M_DEMIR.STUDENTADDRESS")]
public partial class StudentAddress
{
    [Column("ID"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("STUDENT_ID")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Column("CITY", TypeName = "varchar2"), MaxLength(25)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code is as below:

```
[EnableQuery]
public class StudentController : ODataController
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();


    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }


}
```

And WebApiConfig Code is as below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
        builder.EntitySet<StudentAddress>("StudentAddresses");
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: `EnableQuery` should be on the `Get` method. Add `ODataRoute` to the Get method. Add `ODataRoutePrefix("Students")` to the class definition where you now have EnableQuery. Change your url to `http://localhost:7951/odata/Students` (added an s).

Comment: Thank you for answer.Can you give me update code?

Comment: @Demirline - If this worked  for you please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) once the 15 minutes period has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Students")]
public class StudentController : ODataController
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    [EnableQuery(MaxTop = 100)] // MaxTop so you can use the $top in the query string
    [ODataRoute]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(db.Students); // you do want to return something that can be queried
    }
}
```

- [EnableQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) should be on the Get method.
- Add [ODataRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to the Get method.
- Add [ODataRoutePrefix("Students")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.routing.odatarouteprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to the class definition where you now have [EnableQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Change your url to http://localhost:7951/odata/Students (added an s).

Also do not forget to dispose your `DbContext` instance by overriding the `Dispose` method of your controller.

Comment: ODataRoutePrefix and ODataRoute not work.Are they not in Odata.dll?

Comment: @Demirline - they are found in namespace `System.Web.OData.Routing`, Assembly `System.Web.OData`.

Comment: Hi Igor.Thank you for your help.I take error in WebapiConfig. Code is config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());                                                                   Error is "The type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."

Comment: @Demirline - You have to install NuGet packages `Microsoft.OData.Core` and `Microsoft.OData.Edm`

Comment: Hi Igor.If I run "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata" commmand in the Package Manager Console I take this error.(Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0')  Can you help me ?

Comment: @Demirline - It might be you are using a pre-release version?